# Why is groups( ) in igraph (R) not working?

Tags: r, igraph

I just came across something really weird using `igraph` in R. I have an adjacency matrix, M, for a random graph of nodes and links, and I want to obtain the labels of nodes in each connected component. The codes below was working yesterday, yet when I run it today, it keeps saying that

> *Error in UseMethod("groups") :    no applicable method for 'groups' applied to an object of class "list"*

```
library(igraph)
g <- graph.adjacency(M)
comp <- clusters(g)
grp <- groups(comp)
```

I'm totally confused because I literally change nothing. Why is `groups()` not working any more? Can anyone help me out here? Thanks!

Comment: May be you have to create a better example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: `M` isn't defined here so we can't run and test your code. What version of `igraph` are you using? So you have any other packages loaded that might have also defined a function named "groups"?

Comment: Thank you, guys! I deleted R, RStudio, and all the packages and intalled them again. Then everything came back on track ... I don't understand any of this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be a conflict with `dplyr` or another package that also contains a `groups()` function. I was able to fix this error in my code by specifying the package when calling the function using `igraph::groups()`.

Comment: Thank you! It makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

I have ran into the same issue with groups. I have just closed and re-opended R studio, and it fixed the issue.

Comment: Thanks. This starts to sound a bit funny